# Gather mysql query results without having to enter mysql command line

Tags: mysql, bash, grep

I have multiple tables that I want to add to a database, and I anticipate some of the queries failing so I want to gather the pertinent information like the following:

```
mysql> drop table user;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to capture this information on the bash command line. I've tried the following:

```
mysql --force -ujay -p db < create.sql > log.txt 2> error.txt
```

... but only error log gets populated -- how can I acquire the "Query OK" messages external to mysql?

---

I've edited the script so that I'm outputting to a file and then grepping for problems:

```
mysql -vv --force -ujay -p db < create.sql &>> log.txt
grep -i '^Query\|^Warning\|^ERROR' log.txt
```

The problem here is that the results:

```
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 28: Table 'db' already exists
Query OK, 0 rows affected
Query OK, 0 rows affected
```

are NOT in the order of which the queries get executed. The first and third queries are successful, so the order should look as follows:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 28: Table 'db' already exists
Query OK, 0 rows affected
```

The order is EXTREMELY important in this situation.

This is how the log looks after being created:

```
--------------
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 28: Table 'db' already exists
--------------
CREATE TABLE `db` (
  `Host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Db` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Select_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Insert_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Update_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Delete_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Drop_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Grant_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `References_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Index_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_tmp_table_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Lock_tables_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Show_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Execute_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Event_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Trigger_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Db`,`User`),
  KEY `User` (`User`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Database privileges'
--------------
Query OK, 0 rows affected

--------------
CREATE TABLE `db` (
  `Host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Db` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Select_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Insert_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Update_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Delete_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Drop_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Grant_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `References_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Index_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_tmp_table_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Lock_tables_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Show_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Execute_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Event_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Trigger_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Db`,`User`),
  KEY `User` (`User`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Database privileges'
--------------

--------------
CREATE TABLE `db1` (
  `Host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Db` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Select_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Insert_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Update_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Delete_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Drop_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Grant_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `References_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Index_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_tmp_table_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Lock_tables_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Show_view_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Create_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Alter_routine_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Execute_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Event_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Trigger_priv` enum('N','Y') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Db`,`User`),
  KEY `User` (`User`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Database privileges'
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected

Bye
```

As you can see the messages do not appear in the correct order (and I'm not sure why the create table statements appear at all -- something to do with the -vvv flag I assume).

Comment: There is a command switch, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Have you tried using verbose?  So add `-vv` or maybe `-vvv` to the command.

Comment: @user3299633 you can try use a grep or fgrep and a wc -l on that file where are all mysql logs

Comment: Jay, try changing your grep to display line numbers-- to see if they are in the log in the wrong order or if they are grepped in the wrong order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that in linux `stdout` is buffered while `errout` is unbuffered. That basically means that `stdout` will wait until it has e.g. 8kb of data before it writes to the file, while `errout` will write at once, thus resulting in a different order. So your logfile would usually look something like `stderr messages that happened during first 8kb of stdoutdata` - `8kb of stdoutdata` - `stderr messages during next 8kb of stdoutdata` - `next 8kb of stdoutdata` - `...`.

You can force mysql to flush the (stdout) buffer after each query by using the option `-n` or `--unbuffered`, so e.g.

```
mysql -vv -n --force -ujay -p db < create.sql &>> log.txt
grep -i '^Query\|^Warning\|^ERROR' log.txt
```

should give you the correct order.

Btw., `--show-warnings` is false by default, so if you want to get warnings too as your `grep` implies, you might want to add `--show-warnings`.

An alternative would be to just split up your create statements in seperate files (or not put them in one file to begin with) and call mysql for each of them, which would give you the opportunity to react in your program directly to a missing table and it would guarantee the creation order and its logic (e.g. if you create the table `db1`, `db`, `db` and the first one fails, and the second one has a reference to `db1` and therefore fails too, the third table `db` will be created. Correcting `db1` afterwards and repeating it will now not be the same as if it had been correct the first time, as now the second table will fail, because the third already exists, instead of the third table failing because the second table already exists.)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is going to allow me to automate my entire process.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for now, is change the grep to a sed-- assuming the grep is the issue.

```
sed -n '/^Query/p; /^Warning/p; /^Error/p' log.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It produces the same kind of output. I'm afraid this behavior is due to how the mysql command works. I'll add example output to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

This merges the two outputs together.  Will that do what you need?

```
>log.txt  2>&1
```

But I would argue that shell scripting is not the way to execute SQL.  Instead, use some language that has more facilities, such as Perl.